# Can't free memory from 2D dynamical array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am having problem with freeing my memory. I did this many times, and it was working fine. Now, it just stops working (no error, anything, just freeze).

How my code looks like:

```
void args(int argc, char** argv, int *n, int *m, int **matrix, char name[20])
{
int firstIter = TRUE;
int x;
char op;
int** second;

second = NULL;

op = argv[1][0];

for (x = 2; x < argc; x++)
{
    if (!firstIter)
    {
        setName(name, argv[x]);
        loadMatrix(*m, *n, second, *name);
        opMatrix(*m, *n, matrix, second, &*matrix, op);
    }
    else
    {
        setName(name, argv[x]);
        loadSizeMatrix(n, m, name);

        matrix = (int **)malloc(*n * sizeof(int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
            matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(*m * sizeof(int));
        }

        second = (int **)malloc(*n * sizeof(int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
            second[i] = (int *)malloc(*m * sizeof(int));
        }

        loadMatrix(*m, *n, matrix, *name);
        firstIter = FALSE;
    }
}

printMatrix(*m, *n, matrix);

for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
    free(second[i]);
}

free(second[0]); //doesnt work too, and yes, there are data

free(second);
}
```

second is being filled like this (loadMatrix):

```
for (int c = 0; c < radky; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < sloupce; d++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%i", &second[c][d]);
            // printf("%i", matice[c][d]); // dump
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this error?

my full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> //tolower
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE !TRUE

/* konstanty */
const enum {
    MAX_DELKA_SOUBORU = 10000,
    MAX_SOUBOR = 20
}; 

const enum {
    SOUBOR_NENALEZEN = 1,
    SPATNE_ARGUMENTY = 2,
    LIMIT_NAZEV_SOUBOR = 3,
    SPATNY_OP = 4
};

void error(int type);
void zpracovaniArgumentu(int argc, char** argv, char(*nazevSouboru)[MAX_SOUBOR], char(*nazevVystupni)[MAX_SOUBOR], int *n, int *m, int **matice);
void setNazevSouboru(char(*nazev)[MAX_SOUBOR], char *argument);
void vypisMatice(int radky, int sloupce, int **matice);
int nacteniMaticeZeSouboru(int radky, int sloupce, int **matice, char nazev[MAX_SOUBOR]);
int nacteniVelikostiMatice(int *n, int *m, char nazev[MAX_SOUBOR]);
int operaceMatic(int radky, int sloupce, int **prvni, int **druha, int **vysledek, char op);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n, m; // n = sloupce, m = radky pro prvni matici
    int** first;
    char nazevSouboru[MAX_SOUBOR], nazevVystupni[MAX_SOUBOR];
    char op;

    first = NULL;

    zpracovaniArgumentu(argc, argv, &nazevSouboru, &nazevVystupni, &n, &m, &*first);

    /* for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        free(first[i]);
    } */
    free(first);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void error(int type)
{
    switch (type) 
    {
    case SOUBOR_NENALEZEN:  printf("Soubor nenalezen!");
        break;
    case SPATNE_ARGUMENTY:  printf("Program spustte s argumenty [nazev souboru] *[nazev vystupniho souboru]*.\n");
        break;
    case MAX_DELKA_SOUBORU: printf("Prekrocen maximalni limit delky nazvu souboru (%i).\n", MAX_SOUBOR);
        break;
    case SPATNY_OP:         printf("Program spustte s argumenty [nazev souboru] *[nazev vystupniho souboru]*.\n");
        break;
    default:                printf("Nastala chyba!");
        break;
    }
    system("pause");
    exit(type);
}


void zpracovaniArgumentu(int argc, char** argv, char(*nazevSouboru)[MAX_SOUBOR], char(*nazevVystupni)[MAX_SOUBOR], int *n, int *m, int **matice)
{
    int firstIter = TRUE;
    int doSouboru = FALSE;
    int x;
    char op;
    int** second;

    second = NULL;

    op = argv[1][0];

    for (x = 2; x < argc; x++)
    {
        if (!firstIter)
        {
            setNazevSouboru(nazevSouboru, argv[x]);
            nacteniMaticeZeSouboru(*m, *n, &*second, *nazevSouboru);
            operaceMatic(*m, *n, matice, &*second, &*matice, op);
        }
        else if (argv[x][0] == '-')
        {
            switch (argv[x][1])
            {
            case 'n':   doSouboru = TRUE;
                break;
            default:    error(SPATNE_ARGUMENTY);
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (doSouboru)
        {
            setNazevSouboru(nazevVystupni, argv[x]);
        }
        else
        {
            setNazevSouboru(nazevSouboru, argv[x]);
            nacteniVelikostiMatice(n, m, *nazevSouboru);

            matice = (int **)malloc(*n * sizeof(int*));
            for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
                matice[i] = (int *)malloc(*m * sizeof(int));
            }

            second = (int **)malloc(*n * sizeof(int*));
            for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
                second[i] = (int *)malloc(*m * sizeof(int));
            }

            nacteniMaticeZeSouboru(*m, *n, &*matice, *nazevSouboru);
            firstIter = FALSE;
        }
    }

    vypisMatice(*m, *n, matice);

    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        printf("%i",second[i]);
        free(second[i]);
    }

    free(second);
}


void setNazevSouboru(char(*nazev)[MAX_SOUBOR], char *argument)
{
    strcpy(*nazev, argument);
    strcat(*nazev, ".txt"); //nazev souboru
}

int nacteniVelikostiMatice(int *n, int *m, char nazev[MAX_SOUBOR]) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(nazev, "r"); // načtení souboru
    int c;
    int radky = 1;
    int sloupce = 0;
    if (!fp) 
    {
        error(SOUBOR_NENALEZEN);
        exit(2);
    }
    else 
    {
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) 
        {
            //tolower(c);
            if (c == '\n') 
            {
                radky++;
            }
            else if ((isdigit(c)) && (radky == 1)) 
            {
                sloupce++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    *n = sloupce;
    *m = radky;
    return 0;
}

int nacteniMaticeZeSouboru(int radky, int sloupce, int **matice, char nazev[MAX_SOUBOR]) 
{
    int x;

    FILE *fp = fopen(nazev, "r"); // načtení souboru
    if (!fp)
    {
        error(SOUBOR_NENALEZEN);
        exit(2);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < radky; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < sloupce; d++) {
                fscanf(fp, "%i", &matice[c][d]);
                // printf("%i", matice[c][d]); // dump
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int operaceMatic(int radky, int sloupce, int **prvni, int **druha, int **vysledek, char op)
{
    int vysledekClip[10][10];

    for (int c = 0; c < radky; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < sloupce; d++) {
            switch (op) {
                case '+':   vysledekClip[c][d] = prvni[c][d] + druha[c][d];
                            vysledek[c][d] = vysledekClip[c][d]; 
                            break;
                case '-':   vysledekClip[c][d] = prvni[c][d] - druha[c][d];
                            vysledek[c][d] = vysledekClip[c][d];
                            break;
                case '/':   vysledekClip[c][d] = prvni[c][d] / druha[c][d];
                            vysledek[c][d] = vysledekClip[c][d];
                            break;
                case '%':   vysledekClip[c][d] = prvni[c][d] % druha[c][d];
                            vysledek[c][d] = vysledekClip[c][d];
                            break;
                case '*':   vysledekClip[c][d] = prvni[c][d] * druha[c][d];
                            vysledek[c][d] = vysledekClip[c][d];
                            break;
                default:    error(SPATNY_OP);
                            break;
            }
            vysledek[c][d] = vysledekClip[c][d];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void vypisMatice(int radky, int sloupce, int **matice)
{
    int c;
    int d;
    for (c = 0; c < radky; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < sloupce; d++) {
            printf("%i\t", matice[c][d]);
        } printf("\n");
    }
}

void vypisMaticeDoSouboru(int radky, int sloupce, int **matice, char nazevSouboru[MAX_DELKA_SOUBORU])
{
    int c;
    int d;
    for (c = 0; c < radky; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < sloupce; d++) {
            printf("%i\t", matice[c][d]);
        } printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What else you need?

allocation (in code) then `free(second[1]);` is broken too, anywhere....

Comment: I've added the function which fills the matrix. Is it useful for you?

Comment: "I did this many times, and it was working fine" please elaborate

Comment: are you sure that radky and sloupce have the same size as *n and *m?

Comment: @DannyRuijters I am sending these values as arguments of the function, so yes. If I try something like `free(second[1])` it falls too. Same values (n,m) for the printing matrix works fine.

Comment: @Pooya I mean this like I did this in a lot of other programs. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with the 'second' array. You allocate an array of ***n** pointers to int but fill ***m** elements in that array:

```
    second = (int **) malloc(*n * sizeof(int*));<p>
    for (int i = 0; i < *m; i++) {
```

Comment: that's a good observation, you are right, but it didn't solve my problem :( As I told it freeze when I try to free second[0] too (and there are data in it)

Comment: Try to log all the allocated and freed pointers. I would print every pointer returned by malloc() and passed to free() (before calling free()). It might be that you have a memory corruption in the second[] and free() freezes on  releazing unknown pointer

Comment: I have "printMatrix" before it, If I put there "second" matrix, it prints the right values.

Comment: I've tried to print pointers (not their values) and there is some adress of memory

Comment: for example `printf("%i", second[1])` gives me "55598..." but it freezes on free (which is after this dump)

Comment: Am I able to send it to you somehow? It's probably too big to insert it here as it is. Any help could be dontated

Comment: You do not need to publish too much. Just the call to args() with all correct parameters

Comment: I've added my full code. All tips and comments are welcomed. If I can contact you somehow else, I would have a few question :o

Comment: Oh sorry, i've forgot. Args: [op] [file1, file2... fileN]. for example: "+ matrix matrix2 matrix3". Files stands for "matrix.txt" which has inside the values (each line = row, each white space = column)

Comment: I"m very sorry but I have no problem with running this application. It does not either crash or stick.

Comment: I have opened a chat room with the same name as this topic at http://chat.stackoverflow.com
We can continue speaking there

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've remade my program to use these functions like this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439039/load-value-from-file-to-a-value-of-2d-array-pointer), increased the malloc memory and it seems working for now