# Load value from file to a value of 2D array pointer

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

How do I correctly load the values from file to the matrix in another function?

```
void someFunction(int ***matrix, n, m) {
    int c, d;
    FILE *fp = fopen("some.txt", "r"); // načtení souboru
    for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < n; d++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%i", &matrix[c][d]); //4th read throws error
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int **matrix;
    int n = 3; // columns
    int m = 2; // rows

    first = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        first[i] = (int *)malloc(m * sizeof(int));

    someFunction(&matrix, n, m);

    free(matrix);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(first[i]);
}
```

Is `fscanf(fp, "%i", &matice[c][d])` right?

It fails (memory error) at `[1][0]` but `[0][0],[0][1],[0][2]` works fine. I am not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: What's `matice`?  Do you mean `matrix`?

Comment: @johnbollinger Yes, sorry, my fault, misstyped. It's revised now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of pointers, each element set to point to a dynamically-allocated block.  This is *not* a 2D array, though you can index into the overall data structure via the same syntax that you would use for a 2D array.

You have at least two problems:

1. By your allocation strategy, the first index of your array runs from `0` to `n - 1`, and the indexes into the pointed-to arrays run from `0` to `m - 1`.  You reverse that in your read loop, thereby overrunning the bounds of at least one of your arrays if `n` and `m` differ.
2. More significantly, the storage pointer you pass to `fscanf()` is wrong.  In `someFunction()`, variable `matrix` has type `int ***`, and you pass an address of your int **.  The element at index [`c`][`d`] is therefore `(*matrix)[c][d]`, and the address of that element is `&(*matrix)[c][d]`, which is not at all the same thing as `&matrix[c][d]`, nor even the same as `matrix[c][d]`.

Comment: 1. My inattention, thank you
2. That's exactly what I've needed to know!

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
void someFunction(int **matrix, int n, int m) {
    int c, d;
    FILE *fp = fopen("some.txt", "r");
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < m; d++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%i", &matrix[c][d]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int **matrix;
    int n = 3; // rows
    int m = 2; // columns

    matrix = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(m * sizeof(int));

    someFunction(matrix, n, m);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
}
```

Comment: I had it like this, but it breaks on "free(first[1])" :(

Comment: @Lucfia In the your case, which is a bad reason to executing `free(matrix);` ahead.

Comment: `first` is typo as `matrix` :D

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
void someFunction(int **matrix, n, m)
//                   ^^^^
```

You had too many stars. As a result you tried to scan into a pointer, instead of scanning into an int, causing memory corruption.

The call would be `someFunction(first, n, m);`.

It's not clear what `matrix` is for in `main()` - get rid of it (and certainly don't `free` it because you never made it point anywhere).